# include not working in PHP

Tags: php, include, require, include-path

I have a very strange scenario, I have a `file1` in which I am calling `file2`, lets say `include('file2');`
The problem is that once the `file1.php` is loaded in my browser and I make changes to `file2` and upload it, now If I refresh `file1.ph`p the `include(file2.php)` never runs.
I dont know either it is server cache issue or what, I have to run `file2.php` manually in order to see `file1.php` working again.. 
Anyone who can help me that

Comment: Are you getting any error message on the page or in the error log?

Comment: When you say file2.php does not run, do you mean it runs, but executes the old code and not the new code?

Comment: @RyanNaddy no error received..

Comment: @RiggsFolly NO it not even run..

Comment: Is file1 a .php file or a .html file?

Comment: @RiggsFolly file1 is php

Comment: @user1765876 Does whatever file2 does get done when you refresh file1. I assume it must or the page would not refresh properly. Can you tell us what file2 does, or if its small enough paste it into your question.

Comment: @RiggsFolly file2.php makes a facebook call and get some infor regarding a specific ID and then displays (echo) some div and that info

Comment: @user1765876 So what happens after you change file2?

Comment: @RiggsFolly if i make changes to file2.php and then file1.php doesn't load the updated copy of file1.php..

Comment: @user1765876 SORRY? Can you check what you said there??

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes file2.php is included in file1.php, if I make changes to file2.php and then upload it the file1.php doesn't get updated..

Comment: have you tried calling only file2.php? not include..

Comment: @Jay didn't get that.

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh your browser be sure to use :-

```
Windows: ctrl + F5
Mac/Apple: Apple + R or command + R
Linux: F5
```

Otherwise you are probably just refreshing from the browser cache which is not enough, that does not go back to the website and reload the pages.

Comment: Depending on your browser a better option is one the cache plugins for browsers - in Chrome I get this problem all the time and Ctrl F5 is very hit and miss so I use Cache Killer 1.1 and it works a treat

Comment: Do you want to take this to [chat] PHP Chat

Comment: @RiggsFolly cant see u there